# googleapiclient batchGet sequences Google Analytics Reporting API V4

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-api-client

In Analytics 360 there's a way to go into `Behavior > Site Content > Landing Page > Add New Segment > Sequences` and then you can define a sequence of events, say, user goes from page 1 and then goes to page 2 and then searches and then... etc.

I want to be able to pull this data via the GA API v4 using python's `googleapiclient.discovery`. I can do these queries with dimensions and metrics, but I am not sure how to set up a sequence. Here's how I query dimensions and metrics:

```
request = {
      'viewId': view_id',
      'dateRanges': {
          'startDate': datetime.strftime(pd.to_datetime('2018-12-01'),'%Y-%m-%d'),
          'endDate': datetime.strftime(pd.to_datetime('2018-12-31'),'%Y-%m-%d')
      },
      'dimensions': [
          {'name':'ga:date'}        
      ],
      'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}]
    }
```

Then I was looking [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet) and it seemed like the call could be `sequenceSegment` but that was not recognized. And [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments#sequences) it seems to go into it but not in the way `googleapiclient.discovery` describes it.

I'm just a bit lost how to query the sequences report.

Comment: I think I found the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/analyticsreporting/v4/python/latest/analyticsreporting_v4.reports.html). There's a `sequenceSegment` in there, but still unsure how to specify a sequence of pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the segments in the API-Call. In the API-Call you have to specify the "sequence Segment" you want to apply on the data (or you take a predefined Segment from the UI by calling it by ID).

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments#conditions-vs-sequences

```
users::sequence::ga:deviceCategory==desktop;->>ga:deviceCategory==mobile
```

So if I want all Sessions from Users with dimension date triggering Event Category A and after this coming to pagePath B it would look like this (R):

```
google_analytics_4(
  "ID",
  start = '2019-03-18',
  end = '2019-03-18',
  metrics = c("sessions"),
  dimensions = c("date"),
  segments = c("sessions::sequence::ga:eventCategory==A;->>ga:pagePath==B"),
  max_results = 99999999
)
```